# Compare rows of different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a chatting application which uses a 2 different tables.When a user chats something, I want to get his `user id` in conversation. And on the basis of that I want to show their name from `users` table. I am using PHP and MySQL and still a newbie. I am using foreign keys but didn't manage to get what they do. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in your select statement.  [This article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) does a very good job of explaining the concept of joins if you don't understand them

A generic example would be:

```
SELECT b.UserName
FROM Convo a 
INNER JOIN Users b ON a.userId = b.userId
```

However I would need know your specific schema to give exact code.